# Conditional render Header and Footer

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native app where i want to display headers and footers in only some screens and in the rest of the screens i want to hide them. How can we achieve it ?

```js
export default function Router() {
  const {isLoggedIn, isLogoutPressed} = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <Header />
          <AppStack />
          <FooterNavBar />
          {isLogoutPressed && <LogoutModal />}
        </>
      ) : (
        <AuthStack />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

i have tried doing this but i am getting errors

```js
export default function Router() {
  const {isLoggedIn, isLogoutPressed} = useContext(AppContext);
  const route = useRoute();

  const shouldRenderHeader = () => {
    // Check if the current route name is one of the screens where you want to show the header
    const allowedScreens = ['HomeScreen', 'ProfileScreen', 'Profile'];
    return allowedScreens.includes(route.name);
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <Header />
          {shouldRenderHeader(route) && <Header />}
          <AppStack />
          <FooterNavBar />
          {isLogoutPressed && <LogoutModal />}
        </>
      ) : (
        <AuthStack />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**error:**

Error: Couldn't find a route object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

This error is located at:
in Router (created by App)
in AppProvider (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen navigation state changes with [onStateChange](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#onstatechange) and based on that modify the application state to hide/show components. Something like this:

```
const [showHeader, setShowHeader] = useState(true)

<NavigationContainer 
  onStateChange={({routes}) => setShowHeader(routes[routes.length - 1].name == 'Home')}>
  {showHeader && <Header/>}
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```